# CRM Workflow and custom entity

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I created a workflow for my custom entity which will notify me 2 weeks before the expiration date of my product.
I realised that not only the wait condition but even the "Send Email" not working. 
When I am going to System Jobs show their status as "Waiting".
Any ideas guys?

Comment: How are you setting up your wait condition? Can you describe it or throw in a screenshot? Also, you should probably retag this with ms-crm-4 and/or dynamics-crm.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting status usually means your code is throwing an exception. Try to remote debug to the server.
This [link](http://www.patrickverbeeten.com/pages/ContentItemPage.aspx?id=9&item=78&p=true) might help too.